# Get values from multiple tables matching the records with if condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG4At.jpg)I am fetching data from 6 tables namely voucher,sourcing,procurement,vendor,market,farmer i am matching the id present in voucher table with sourcing and procurement table and retrieving data, my problem is in procurement table i when i get the source as farmer i want to get all the data from farmer table and with vendor and market tables also

I tried using inner join with switch case and inner query but i am getting error

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT voucher.voucher_id, sourcing.source_proc_id, procurement.procure_id,
case procurement.procure_from
    when 'farmer' then 
               (select procurement.procure_source, farmer.* from   procurement inner join farmer on 
procurement.procure_source =  farmer.farmer_id)
    ELSE 'No Data' END AS Result
  FROM vendor,market,farmer,
       ((voucher inner join sourcing on voucher.voucher_source_id =               sourcing.source_proc_id) inner join procurement on voucher.voucher_proc_id= procurement.procure_id) WHERE voucher.voucher_status = "ACTIVE" group by voucher.voucher_id
```

**farmer table**

```
 farmer_id | farmer_name | farmer_address
  -----------------------------------------
  F_001     | Name        | Address
```

**vendor table**

```
  vendor_id | vendor_name 
  -----------------------
  V_001     | Vendor
```

**voucher table**

```
 voucher_id | voucher_source_id | voucher_proc_id
  ------------------------------------------------
  VOUC_001   | SRC_001           | PROC_001
```

**Procurement Table**

```
procure_id | procure_from | procure_source
  -------------------------------------------
  PROC_001   | farmer       | F_001
  PROC_002   | vendor       | V_001
```

> ```
>   Expected output
>
>   voucher_id | voucher_source_id | procure_id | procure_from | procure_source | farmer_name
>   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   VOUC_001   | SRC_001           | PROC_001   | farmer       | F_001          | Name
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Please tell what is the error you are getting.

In the meanwhile you may try the following. It is very hard for me to test whether it will work or not. So please tell the outcome and the previous error.

```sql
SELECT 
    voucher.voucher_id,
    sourcing.source_proc_id,
    procurement.procure_id,
    CASE
        WHEN
            procurement.procure_from = 'farmer'
        THEN
            (SELECT 
                    procurement.procure_source, farmer.*
                FROM
                    procurement
                        INNER JOIN
                    farmer ON procurement.procure_source = farmer.farmer_id)
        ELSE 'No Data'
    END AS Result
FROM
    vendor,
    market,
    farmer,
    ((voucher
    INNER JOIN sourcing ON voucher.voucher_source_id = sourcing.source_proc_id)
    INNER JOIN procurement ON voucher.voucher_proc_id = procurement.procure_id)
WHERE
    voucher.voucher_status = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY voucher.voucher_id;
```

I hope it works.

Comment: There is no problem in SQL for which the above would be a valid solution.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG4At.jpg
please find the above link which shows the error which i am getting

Comment: Did you try removing "AS Result"? I guess you are not using it anywhere else anyways?

Comment: yes i tried removing and its giving me an error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

if i am using () after then i am not getting any warning but i am getting error  #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

if i remove complete inner query the query is executing but i am able to get predefined string  as below

CASE
        WHEN
            procurement.procure_from = 'farmer'
        THEN
            'FARMER'
        ELSE 'No Data'
    END